# Where are you supposed to get the Base URL for an embedded device?

Tags: c#, xml, upnp, base-url

In UPnP, you have a Root device who has an .xml file that describes himself and a bit about his various embedded devices.

In that file, there are no BaseURLs.  I get the BaseURL from the 'Host:' field in the 'OK' response to my M-Search.  I use that BaseURL to get the Description for the Root Device and its embedded devices.

However, I am having a problem figuring out the right way to get the proper BaseURLs for the embedded devices.

Suppose I have a Parent (root) device with 2 embedded devices (Fred) and (Bob).

```
Parent BaseURL: 192.168.1.10:1960   UUID: MOMMY_10
  Fred BaseURL: 192.168.1.10:1961   UUID: FRED_10
  Bob  BaseURL: 192.168.1.10:1962   UUID: BOB_10
```

Parent has a Service called 'Banker' which has a service defined at:

```
<SCPDURL>_urn-company-com-serviceId-Banker_scpd.xml</SCPDURL>
```

Fred has a Service called 'MoneyUser' which has a SCPDURL defined at:

```
<SCPDURL>FRED_10/_urn-company-com-serviceId-MoneyUser_scpd.xml</SCPDURL>
```

Bob also has a Service called 'MoneyUser' which has a SCPDURL defined at:

```
<SCPDURL>BOB_10/_urn-company-com-serviceId-MoneyUser_scpd.xml</SCPDURL>
```

If I want to get the scpd.xml files to look at the service details for Fred and Bob, I need to replace the UUID (FRED_10) or (BOB_10) from the SCPDURL with the BaseURL for Fred or Bob respectively.  However, I'm in trouble because their BaseURL is NOT the same as their Parent's BaseURL. And it is not in the Description file.

The only place I can find it is when the services announce themselves with a Notify and have their UUID and their Host: values.  I could wait until I receive those notifications and then be able to hook up the Services to the appropriate BaseURL for the given UUID.

Is it supposed to be this complicated, or is there an easier way to do this that I haven't thought of yet?

Also, are the  values correct, or should they be an absolute URL that is directly accessible?  Should the following be replaced with the line below it?

```
<SCPDURL>BOB_10/_urn-company-com-serviceId-MoneyUser_scpd.xml</SCPDURL>
<SCPDURL>192.168.1.10:1962/_urn-company-com-serviceId-MoneyUser_scpd.xml</SCPDURL>
```

The UPnP devices that I'm talking to are generated using the Intel UPnP Library.  I'm not sure if the SCPDURL is correctly implemented, or if I'm supposed to jump through hoops to get to the correct BaseURL for the SCPDURL to use.

Any opinions and help on this topic would be greatly appreciated !!

For now, I'm just going to only get the scpd.xml after I receive a notify from the appropriate UUID that has a Host: value that I can use for the BaseURL for that embedded device.

Thanks,
Curtis

Comment: It seems a bit odd that your embedded devices have different IP addresses from their parent.  That doesn't seem correct - if the devices are available from different network adapters, there won't be any way to guarantee that the root device is available all the time it's embedded devices are.  If you're running different devices on either different physical hosts or different network adapters, it'd seem clearer to announce them as independent root devices.

Comment: Actually, they have the same IP, but different ports.  I'll edit my original posting to reflect that.  Thanks for pointing that out.